# Expected value of max function of a random variable: understanding the proof

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, expected-value, cumulative-distribution-functions

Consider a random variable $\phi$. Assume $\mathbb{E}[\phi]<\infty$. Let $F_\phi(t)$ be its cumulative distribution function. Let $(a)^+=\max\{0,a\}$.

I am trying to understand the proof of the following result
$$\mathbb{E}[(\phi-z)^+]=\int_z^\infty(1-F_\phi(t))dt$$
It proceeds like this
$$
\mathbb{E}[(\phi-z)^+]=\int_z^\infty(t-z)dF_\phi(t)=\lim_{y\to\infty}\int_z^y(t-z)dF_\phi(t)
$$
Now, focusing on the argument of the limit, and using integration by parts we get
$$
\int_z^y(t-z)dF_\phi(t)=(t-z)F_\phi(t)\vert^y_z-\int_z^\infty F_\phi(t)dt$$
So far so good. **But the next step confuses me**
$$(t-z)F_\phi(t)\vert^y_z-\int_z^\infty F_\phi(t)dt=-(y-z)(1-F_\phi(y))+\int_z^\infty (1-F_\phi(t))dt$$

**I fail to understand why the last equality holds**.
For the first term, I would expect
$$(y-z)F_\phi(y)-(z-z)F_\phi(z)=(y-z)F_\phi(y)$$
but instead a $1-F_\phi$ shows up there and in the integral.
**My guess** is that it is probably some simple equivalence regarding $F_\phi(t)$ and $1-F_\phi(t)$ but I cannot figure it out. **Any hints?**

Comment: Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4750938/how-to-properly-switch-the-order-of-integration/4750944#4750944

Comment: $\int_z^\infty F_\phi(t)dt=\infty$, so you should avoid this integral.

Answer (score 0):

When you apply integration by parts, you are integrating $dv\equiv dF_\phi(t)$. It is common to choose the integration constant to be $0$, but in a general fashion, $$\int dF_\phi(t)dt=F_\phi(t)+c,$$ with $c\in\mathbb{R}$ arbitrary. Then, a way to obtain the equation that you are looking for is to take the antiderivative with $c=-1$. Note that the result of integration by parts does not depend on the candidate you chose from the family of antiderivatives.

Edit: Let us show that this does not depend on $c$. Integration by parts states that $$\int_a^b udv=uv|_a^b-\int_a^bvdu. $$ If we take $u=t-z$ and $dv = dF_\phi(t),$ $du=dt$ and $v=F_\phi(t)+c.$ Therefore,

$$\int_z^y (t-z)dF_\phi(t) = (t-z)[F_\phi(t)+c]\Big|_z^y - \int_z^y \left(F_\phi(t)+c\right)dt \\ =(y-z)\left[F_\phi(y)+c\right]-\int_z^y F_\phi(t)dt - c(y-z)\\ = (y-z)F_\phi(y)-\int_z^y F_\phi(t)dt,$$
which is independent of $c$.

Comment: thanks. This helps. Regarding your last comment, if I choose a different $c$, for example $c=0$ or $c=1$, the result does changes significantly. By choosing $c=0$ I get $(y-z)F_\phi(y)-\int_z^yF(t)d t$. If I put this back into the limit, the result is totally different. Am I missing anything?

Comment: @pele see my edit.

Comment: Thanks @Julian. Shouldn't I expect to see the same result of the limit $\lim_{y\to\infty}$ regardless of the $c$ and, in particular, for the last expression $\lim_{y\to\infty}(y-z)F_\phi(y)-\int_z^yF_\phi(t)d t$? Does this limit give $\int_z^\infty(1-F_\phi(t))d t$? The first term gives $\infty$, the second $\int_z^\infty F_\phi(t)d t$, which looks quite different from the expected result. Any suggestion?